# Cakephp Identify user using REST API

Tags: php, api, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm developing an API for an application that I'm creating. This application will get all the information from this API (first will auth the user, then get information)

Right now, I'm trying to make the user send a username and password to the API, it validates the information and returns if it's "ok" or "not", very simple to start only. I know all the security involved in this, just need to get this working.

Already managed to send the username and passsword on the API Side (and i'm 100% sure that the data is correctly saved). Though, when I call

`$this->Auth->identify($this->request->data);`

It always returns false to me (already tried with parameters and without, result is the same).

I'm using the HttpRequester, firefox plugin, to send information.

I've did a debug of $this->request->data to see if the information is correct, and it is. Can't do a find on database since the password is being hashed.

The database password field is a varchar with 300 length (already tried with 255, also no work)

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

```
      $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]);

     if($this->request->is('POST')){
        //debug($this->request->data);
        $user = $this->Auth->identify($this->request->data);
    }
```

Users Table:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
];

/**
* Hash password
*
*/
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}

protected function _getFullName()
{
    if(isset($this->_properties['full_name'])){
        return ucwords(mb_strtolower($this->_properties['full_name']));
    }
}
```

ps: Also tried doing the following (replacing the variables form post, but also no luck)

```
$this->request->data['username'] = "xxxx";
$this->request->data['password'] = "zzzz";
```

Comment: In the request data you must use the custom field names too, ie `email` instead of `username`. The `username` key is just the option name by which the authenticator can access your configured field/column name.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here

```
    'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email', //email is your database field
                    'password' => 'password' // password is your database field name
                ]
            ],
```

Your code should be

```
      'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
```

Details check [Configuring Authentication Handlers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: Hi there @tarikul05. Thanks for the answer! Though, on my database, the two fields I use is email and password

Comment: then `$this->request->data['username']` should be `$this->request->data['email']`

Comment: That was it @tarikul05. Thanks for the help :)